# Parse to collectionview images in wrong order

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage, uicollectionview

I'm trying to load images from Parse to show them on collection view and the order doesn't come up right sometimes.  Usually first image comes out right but the subsequent ones don't come out in order at least 25% of the time.

I've looked up other answers and I've tried em all like "orderbyascending", "making a dictionary" but still no luck.

I have Parse classes called "Fhooder" and "items" and they are related.

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Fhooder")
        let id = (user.valueForKey("fhooder")?.objectId)! as String

        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(id) { (fhooder: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && fhooder != nil {

                let relation = fhooder!.relationForKey("items")
                let query2 = relation.query()

                query2!.orderByAscending("createdAt")
                query2!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (items: [PFObject]?, error2: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error2 == nil && items != nil {
                        var index = items!.count
                        for item in items! {
                            let pic = item["photo"] as! PFFile
                            let name = item["itemName"] as! String

                            pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                if (error == nil) {
                                    let picture = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                                    self.itemPictures[index] = picture

                                    let counter = self.arrItemNames.count - 1
                                    if index == counter {
                                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                    }
                                    index++

                                }
                            })

                            if index != 0 {

                                self.arrItemNames.append(name)

                                index--
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my collectionview

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collCell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ManageCollectionViewCell

    cell.foodImage.image = self.itemPictures[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my revision.  Just to make things simple I got rid of index, change itemPictures from dictionary to UIImage array, took Ray's advise to reload everytime and also put everything under getDataInBackgroundWithBlock to get rid of any time sync error.  However, images are still not in the order by the date they're created.  What's really weird is about 2/3 of the time it IS loaded in the right order.

```
var itemPictures : [UIImage] = []
var arrItemNames : [String] = []

if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Fhooder")
        let id = (user.valueForKey("fhooder")?.objectId)! as String

        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(id) { (fhooder: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && fhooder != nil {

                let relation = fhooder!.relationForKey("items")
                let query2 = relation.query()

                query2!.orderByAscending("createdAt")
                query2!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (items: [PFObject]?, error2: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error2 == nil && items != nil {
                        for item in items! {
                            let pic = item["photo"] as! PFFile

                            pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                                if (error == nil) {
                                    let name = item["itemName"] as! String
                                    let picture = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                                    self.itemPictures.append(picture)
                                    self.arrItemNames.append(name)

                                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            else {

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is suffering from the "pyramid hell" you get when nesting asynchronous calls. It get very hard to follow the flow, and very hard to debug. I recommend that you either rethink the structure of your calls, or that you use a framework for introducing a Promises-like structure to your code. Since Parse is using the Bolts Framework for this, you already have this installed. And it is fairly well documented as well, [here](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS).

Your code could then look something like this:

```
var itemPictures : [UIImage] = []
var arrItemNames : [String] = []

if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Fhooder")
    let id = (user.valueForKey("fhooder")?.objectId)! as String

    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(id).continueWithBlock {
        (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask in
        let fhooder = task.result as! PFObject

        let relation = fhooder.relationForKey("items")
        let query2 = relation.query()
        return query2.findObjectsInBackground()
    }.continueWithBlock {
        (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask in
        let items = task.result as! [PFObject]

        // Do what you need with the objects here...
    }
}
```

That said, you probably don't want to wait until all images are downloaded, so I would recommend that each cell is responsible for downloading its own picture asynchronously and then the code will update each cell as the photo has finished downloading. You can find tutorials for this by googling.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I'll look into Bolts Framework.  I would really appreciate it if you could explain to me little more in depth or point me a relevant link about cell downloading its own picture, because I'm still struggling to find the right answer on google.  Are you suggesting I should implement the parse call that retrieves image into either collectionView(cellForItemAtIndexPath) or collectionViewCell?

Comment: Check out this article by Natasha. You should be able to port it to downloading Parse image data instead of using the url in her example http://natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/
This is not an example of what I said, but it is another approach you can use.

Comment: This Apple sample project could also lead you on the way: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Ah..objective-c...  Ok. Time to translate. ^^;;  Well, thank you very much for your help @Lonely Penguin.  I'll look into those examples.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `arrItemNames` is, my guess is that your problem is when you increment `index` in `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`.

It is asynchronous, so `index` is only being incremented at the moment the response arrives.

Comment: I apologize for not being specific. arrItemNames is just an empty string array and index does print out to be incremental (starting 4.3.2.1.0 and then increment back up 1.2.3 Then load the collection view.)

Comment: and self.itemPictures is dictionary array [int : UIImage]

Comment: I have to understand more to help you. Why are you doing this : `let counter = self.arrItemNames.count - 1`?

Comment: Because self.arrItemNames.append gets processed before image data gets downloaded so if there are 4 images, self.arrItemNames will append 4 items before index becomes 0.  After that it'll get the picture data until the index is same as counter.  Since the dictionary index starts at 0, 4 items will be appended at 0, 1, 2, and 3.  So when the index becomes 3 I want the processing to stop.  Hence self.arrItemNames.count - 1 = 3 = counter.

Comment: @young you still didn't say why you were doing this.

Comment: @young I think your needlessly complicating things. I just can't see why you're doing things the way you're doing them. First off, you should just reloadData every time, so that the user can see the items as they come in. Second, expecting code that is placed after a block of code to occur _before_ that code, just makes no sense, asynchronous or not. If your asynchronous call responds super fast, you can't decrement your index at the appropriate time.

Comment: @young I'm willing to help but when I need to know what you are trying to achieve, not what your code does. I can read that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Ray!  I wanted to make things efficient so the load time and the memory would be reserved by reloading only once.  I do agree it might be counter intuitive to set counter from other elements that I'm asynchronously downloading.  To make things simple I'll revise this.

Comment: @young Oh wait so all is this to save a reloadData?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`, which is an asynchronous call.

When you download 10 images at the same time, the time it takes to complete the downloads depends on the size of each file, not the time at which it was saved.

So your biggest file arrives last, and gets appended last, even if it was saved first.

You are facing this problem because you are not properly structuring your code. The image download for the cell should be taken care of by the cell itself, in a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. It should not be in the `UIViewController`. This is bad design.

Comment: Can you explain more in specific what you mean by "the cell should be taken care of by the cell itself?".  If you see my func collectionView, I DID set a custom UICollecitonViewCell called ManageCollectionViewCell.  I didn't put it up because it was apparent from the collectionView.  BTW, if you feel like I'm wasting your time, feel free to stop.  I don't think you're really understanding my issue either.

Comment: It's not that "the cell should be taken of by the cell itself", its "the image download for the cell should be taken care of by the cell itself". The download should happen inside your `ManageCollectionViewCell.swift` file. @young